# coffeescript vs react for a single page application users dashboard

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iced-coffeescript

As I'm new. I have to design a users dashboard which almost a single page application and also having a lot of functionalities. I'm planning to use coffeescript or react.js but not clear. Please suggest one of language.

Comment: reactjs is not a programming language. You're comparing an orange with a mobile phone.

Comment: Fun fact : in France, Orange is a mobile service provider.

Answer (score 0):

To me it seems like you are comparing apples with pears.

Coffeescript is a scripting language and can be compared to Typescript, ES6, etcetera that is compiled down to Javascript.

React is a library that is build on Javascript (or Coffeescript, Typescript, ES6) and can be compared to Angular 2, Elm, etcetera.